# How to show that $f : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(t)=(t , \sin(1/t))$ is continuous using open sets?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

How can I prove the function $f : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(t)=\left(t , \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)$ is a continuous function using that $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set for every $U$ open set in $\Bbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: IMO that's too much work to prove that directly from the definition. Why can't you use some well known properties of continuous functions? I.e. compositions and products of continuous functions are continuous. Inverse $1/f(x)$ of non-zero, continous function is continous. $\sin$ and the identity functions are continuous. You can prove each statement yourself if you need to. Arguably proving that $\sin$ is continuous would be the most difficult one, depending on your definition of $\sin$.

Comment: @freakish yes that seems the easiest way. But as I'm working with the topology subject I tend to use its definitions so I try to avoid calculus theory.

Comment: Well, you have to use calculus. How would you define $\sin$ or $\frac{1}{t}$ otherwise? At least proving that $\sin$ is continuous is a purely analytical job.

Comment: @freakish mmmh you are right. As a student I doubt sometimes if I can use certain things. Thanks

Comment: @Álvaro What is the Topology on $\left( 0, \infty \right)$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$? Is it the topology induced by the usual metrics? Everything can be proved using definitions, though sometimes it can be a bit exhausting and lengthy. However, I intend to solve it using the definition alone and hence I would like to know if the topologies are induced by the usual metrics?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Yes, in both sets the topology defined is the induced by usal metrics